# How do I rotate a parent sphere to a specific position by tapping on one of its sub nodes?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a sphere (earthSphere) with specific plotted points represented by other smaller spheres (coordinateSpheres) that are child nodes of the earthSphere. When a user tap’s any of the coordinateSpheres, I would like to rotate the (earthSphere) so that the tapped coordinateSphere faces the camera.

1. earthSphere is a rootnode of the main scene and positioned at SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
2. cameraNode is a rootnode of the main scene and positioned at SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 20)
3. coordinateSpheres are child nodes of the earthSphere at random points on the surface.

The user can currently rotate and zoom the earthSphere. I would like to keep the camera static at SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 20) and simply rotate the earthSphere (when the user taps a child node), aligning the child node to face the camera as if it is being displayed front and center.

[Example image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pqF1.png) (Y+ is up and -Z is out (away))

```
  @objc func sceneTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = recognizer.location(in: self)

    let hitResults = self.hitTest(location, options: nil)

    if hitResults.count > 0 {

        let result = hitResults[0]

        let node = result.node

        print("The location is:", location)
        print(node.name as Any)
        print(node.position)

        if node.name != "earth" {

            print("earth position is", self.node.position)
            print("earth euler is", self.node.eulerAngles)
            print("earth Presentation is", self.node.presentation.position)
            print("earth transform is",self.node.transform)
            print("earth scale is",self.node.scale)
            print("sim world", self.node.simdWorldOrientation)
            print("sim rotation",self.node.simdRotation)
            print("sim front", self.node.simdWorldFront)

            print("******break********")

            print("denver position is", node.position)
            print("denver euler is", node.eulerAngles)
            print("denver Presentation is",node.presentation.position)
            print("denver transform is", node.transform)
            print("earth scale is", node.scale)
            print("sim world", node.simdWorldOrientation)
            print("sim rotation", node.simdRotation)
            print("sim front", node.simdWorldFront)

        }

    }

} 
Print data:
earth position is SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
earth euler is SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 1.57079637, z: 0.0)
earth Presentation is SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
earth transform is SCNMatrix4(m11: -4.37113883e-08, m12: 0.0, m13:    -1.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 1.0, m32: 0.0,    m33: -4.37113883e-08, m34: 0.0, m41: 0.0, m42: 0.0, m43: 0.0, m44: 1.0)
earth scale is SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0)
sim world simd_quatf(real: 0.707107, imag: float3(0.0, 0.707107, 0.0))
sim rotation float4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.5708)
sim front float3(-1.0, 0.0, -5.96046e-08)
******break********
denver position is SCNVector3(x: -3.71508956, y: 3.19556522, z: -0.993212819)
denver euler is SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -0.0, z: 0.0)
denver Presentation is SCNVector3(x: -3.71508956, y: 3.19556522, z: -0.993212819)
denver transform is SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0,    m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: -3.71508956, m42: 3.19556522, m43: -0.993212819, m44: 1.0)
earth scale is SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0)
sim world simd_quatf(real: 0.707107, imag: float3(0.0, 0.707107, 0.0))
sim rotation float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
sim front float3(-1.0, 0.0, -5.96046e-08)
```

The user chooses a location from Google Places, then I use the Lat and Long to plot the current location on the globe. With the information provided, I should be able to correctly spin the globe to the correct orientation when the user taps it. Currently I am using hit testing to find the child node being tapped, and that works good. When it comes to rotating the earthSphere so that the child node that was tapped on is facing the camera (Facing the user), that's where I fall short. I have tried every action available, transforms, euler angles etc. and I cannot make it work and have been at it all day. Any help, or a push in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!  P.S. I have been a long-time reader of SO, and have learned a ton. Looking forward to some feedback!

Comment: "Currently I am using hit testing to find the child node being tapped. I have tried every action available, transforms, euler angles etc."  Nobody sees it except you.

Comment: You should look into notifications. You can have listeners set up to look for specific events and react to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! So just to clarify, the hit testing is working good, and I can put my action inside the hit test function per tapped node. The reaction is where I am having trouble. Conceptually I cannot figure out how to adjust the earthSphere so that the tapped node is facing the camera (Straight at the user).

Comment: This question title and contents don’t seem to match and neither seems to actually describe what you want nor is it a question about Scenekit specifically.

Comment: I think your question comes down to several basic questions such as how to rotate using euler angles and how to convert degrees to radians, how to get the angle between two objects (between the worldposition of the earth and worldposition of the child node) etc which have all been asked and answered in various forms here on SO. What El Tomato meant with his comment is try to put some code together where you try to do what you describe and maybe we can help out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated the contents and provided an example of what I am trying to do. The question can be formatted better, I will work on a better match. Thank you for the help.